# SpringBoot JMS Listener: Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms, websphere-8, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have Spring Boot application which listen IBM MQ Queue via `@JmsListener` annotation as below from component class. The MQ properties (hostname, channel, port, etc) are set from *yaml* file.

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "<QueueName>")
 public void receiveMessage(BytesMessage msg) { 
     //snippet to read msg
 }
```

The MQ dependencies are added in gradle build as below,

```
compile("com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:0.0.2") {  
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
```

This works fine and listening the message as long as I run the application on local with Tomcat container. But if I package this as EAR and deploy to Wesbphere8.5 server, it throws below exception and listener is not reading the message from queue. I confirmed that all the run-time dependencies are packaged in EAR. Tried with different versions of MQ dependencies but no luck.

> 2018-07-10 15:21:16,531 ERROR DefaultMessageListenerContainer     - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'QueueName' -
>   retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=34,
>   maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in
>   the Java(tm) MQI.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException:
>   CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received.
>   [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0]

Need help to fix this issue.

Comment: I guess you will get more information about this problem in `AMQERR01.LOG` of the Queue Manager.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue like this. This happens because of missing configurations on IBM MQ Connection with your JMS Application. In My case, I got an authorization related exception but I set the correct user credentials for the IBM mq. when I checked the IBM mq site, the userName is different and that is not which I configured in my spring application.

```
#IBM MQ JMS Configuration
ibm.mq.queueManager={QUEUE_MANAGER}
ibm.mq.channel={CHANNEL_NAME}
ibm.mq.connName={HOST_NAME(HOST_PORT)}
ibm.mq.user={USER_NAME}
ibm.mq.password={PASSWORD}
```

Then I added the below property to Use compatibility mode when authenticating with a queue manager.
Here we override the authentication mode. This should not normally be needed with **current maintenance levels of MQ V8 or V9**, but some earlier levels sometimes got get it wrong and then this flag can be set to "**false**"

```
ibm.mq.user-authentication-m-q-c-s-p=false
```

Please Refer [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=authentication-connection-java-client) for more details